# Android Studio Lint and Code Inspection not picking up VectorPath issueId

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, lint, android-lint

I introduced a `vector` drawable that has a long path (> 800 characters) in my Android app.

However, when I perform code inspection (Code --> Inspect Code) or run `./gradlew app:lintDebug` on my Android app, I do not see the `VectorPath` issue being reported in lint, even though I have `VectorPath` enabled in lint. Static analysis seems to pick up the issue though (as shown below in screenshots).

Does anyone know why `VectorPath` issues are not being reported? (I checked the disabled checks but VectorPath isn't one of them)

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Comment: Filed an issue with Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237636117